# testing an method in an angular component without dependencies

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testing, karma-jasmine

I'm working on testing in angular  my project was created using the CLI so please no need for testing set up. I have checked out the docs

https://angular.io/guide/testing

and these videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XKVBLVlTjeE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-kumGACGYk

and I find myself increasingly annoyed. I'm looking for an example of how to test a method being used. Never mind dependencies, never mind async calls (my style sheet and html are loaded from separate files so i know we need a async call at the beginning im just saying never mind observable or promises right now)

my ask so this can start making sense is can someone please write a test for the following code and comment it throughout?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Venue} from '../../models/venue/venue.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-venuelist',
  templateUrl: './venuelist.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./venuelist.component.css']



 /* takes price number and returns number amount of $ */
        makePrice(n){
          let r = '';
          let c = 0;
          while(c < n){
            r = r + '$';
            c++;
          }
          return r;
```

Comment: `it('should do something', () => { expect(new SomeUnknownComponent().makePrice(0)).toBe(''); });` You're making it hard for us to give you a good answer by not posting the relevant code. So you're shooting yourself in the foot.

Comment: actually this was absolutely perfect! Please submit it as an answer so i can give you points. This is nice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to call a method of a class. So you need to create an instance of that class, and then call the method:

```
it('should do something', () => { 
  expect(new Venuelist().makePrice(0)).toBe(''); 
});
```

Comment: so the component name is venuelist so it would be new venuelist().makePrice(0)).toBe('');

Comment: Glad you figured that out. I would have used the right name from the start if you had posted the relevant code. See what I mean?

Comment: i did though the app selector is the componenent name appeneded to app- by default on the cli